# The type or namespace name 'RayCastHit2D' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried following the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waj6i9cQ6rM and after almost completing it I got this error

> error:Assets\EnemyBehaviour.cs(19,13): error CS0246: The type or
> namespace name 'RayCastHit2D' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemybehaivor : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    #region Public Variables
    public Transform rayCast;
    public LayerMask raycastMask;
    public float rayCastLength;
    public float attackDistance;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float timer; //Timer for cooldown between attacks
    #endregion

    #region Private Variables
    private RayCastHit2D hit;
    private GameObject target;
    private Animator anim;
    private float distance;
    private bool attackMode;
    private bool inRange;
    private bool cooling;
    private float intTimer;
    #endregion

    void Awake()
    {
        intTimer = timer;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (inRange)
        {
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayCast.position, Vector2.left, rayCastLength, raycastMask);
            RaycastDebugger();
        }
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            EnemyLogic();
        }
        else if(hit.collider == null)
        {
            inRange = false;
        }

        if(inRange == false)
        {
            anim.SetBool("canWalk", false);
            StopAttack();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trig)
    {
        if(trig.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            target = trig.gameObject;
            inRange = true;
        }
    }

    void EnemyLogic()
    {
        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position);

        if(distance > attackDistance)
        {
            Move();
            StopAttack();
        }
        else if(attackDistance >= distance && cooling == false)
        {
            Attack();
        }

        if (cooling)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        anim.SetBool("canWalk", true);


        if (!anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Skel_attack"))
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void Attack()
    {
        timer = intTimer;
        attackMode = true;
        
        anim.SetBool("canWalk", false);
        anim.SetBool("Attack", true);
    }

    void StopAttack()
    {
        cooling = false;
        attackMode = false;
        anim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }

    void RaycastDebugger()
    {
        if(distance > attackDistance)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(rayCast.position, Vector2.left * rayCastLength, Color.red);
        }
        else if(attackDistance > distance)
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(rayCast.position, Vector2 * rayCastLength, Color.green);
        }     
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A typo? It should be `RaycastHit2D` rather than `RayCastHit2D`.